# setShadowOffset crash on iOS 3.x

Tags: ios, calayer

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[CALayer setShadowOffset:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2f86d0'

```
cell.shadowView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
cell.shadowView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
cell.shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
cell.shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 6;
cell.shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read CALayer class reference everything is written in the apple's documentation.

Comment: it support Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
could you please advise me about how to fix this error?

Comment: @RAGOpoR Where did you look? [`It is available 3.2 and later.`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/shadowOffset) They were made available only in iPad 1 first and later added to iPhone and iPods in 4.0 release.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

sorry if i'm missing

Comment: @RAGOpoR At the top, you see the class' availability. `CALayer`s were available from iOS 2.0. If you go down to the description of properties or methods, their availability will be listed. This can happen as methods & properties can be added/deprecated with newer releases.